# namespace-manager in Mulesoft

Tags: mule

We are receiving files with 2 different namespace URI but one namespace URI at a time in each file, also the namespace prefix for both the namespace URI are same. Below is my splitter condition and it only works for one namespace URI. when the file with other namespace URI is received the splitter condition fails. How to make the splitter condtion work for both the scenarios. Please suggest.

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="wd" uri="urn:com.test.report/*********A"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="wd" uri="urn:com.test1.report/*********B"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>

<splitter expression="#[xpath3('/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry', payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define two namespaces w1 and w2 in namespace manager. Use choice block - when & otherwise to check namespace of xml u r getting and then use corresponding splitter.

Alternatively u can ignore namespace as shown below

```
#[xpath3('/*:Report_Data/*:Report_Entry',payload,'NODESET')]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The '/*:Report_Data/*:Report_Entry' condition  works perfectly in my scenario.